# Html page is not accesing files in img catalog. Problem with root

Tags: html, css, styles

I have structure on my server as below:

[image]
The problem is that only one picture is loading and it is from my css file:

```
header.masthead {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: calc(10rem - 72px);
  background: url("../img/img_background.jpg");
}
```

from css catalog- one back to this main catalog, and than img. But in index.html I can`t access file using:

```
<img src="img/thmbl_Makeup_1.jpg">
```

The picture won`t be displayed that way. Do someone know why?

Comment: send your link to check that for you

Comment: `../img/img_background.jpg` relative path looks good to me, are you accessing the image from `index.html`? what exactly the issue you're facing when accessing the image?

Comment: Yes, and the path incuded in style.css ->../img/img_background.jpg is working fine. But I am unable to access other files using statement <img src="img/thmbl_Makeup_1.jpg"> in  index.html file

Comment: Ok, so from where you're tying to access `Makeup_1.jpg`? is it same `index.html`? if so add two dots and slash in front, why this is different than the first url?

Comment: Ok, I have found a solution, I have accessed thmbl_Makeup_1.jpg from index file when I have changed code to  <img src="img/thmbl_makeup_1.jpg"> (simple m, not capital). And it works fine, even when the file has name thmbl_Makeup_1.jpg (capital M)